# how to convert a zip file entry to ZipFile with c# asp ionic library?

Tags: c#, zip

im using ionic library to read zip file in c#

i have many zip files in one zip file,i read the zip file but i can't read the subZip files

i have made this portion of code here:

```cs
foreach (var sessionEntry in subjectSessions.Entries)
{
    using (MemoryStream entryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        sessionEntry.OpenReader().CopyTo(entryStream);
        ZipFile sessionZIPFile = ZipFile.Read(entryStream);
    }
}
```

but it's not working,it always gives me the same exception

**Cannot read that as a ZipFile,Ionic.Zip.BadReadException: Could not read block - no data!  (position 0x00000000)**

i have tried calling extract on sessionEntry object,didn't work too

how can i read the subZip files?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you copied the extracted content to the stream and before you read it, you need to manually reset the stream position, like so

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: it worked but what is the difference if i put position to 0? thanks a lot man

Comment: After you write to it, the stream position is at the end of the extracted content, and the reader won't know if it's supposed to rewind (after all, we might be giving it a bunch of file put right next to each other), so we need to manually do that.